# Attributes in Excel and FME

Tags: fme-form, excel

I have a excel and a shapefile.I want to check whether the attributes present in the excel matches the one in the shapefile using FME

Comment: I tried schemamapper and was able to view the tables but have no idea how to check the attributes in shapefile and excel.

Comment: There is an edit button beneath your question that will enable you to update it with that additional information.  [How to frame a good question?](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/how-to-frame-a-good-question) is well worth reviewing if you are new to our site.

Comment: Are you aware that dbf file can be opened with excel (shp comes with shp , dbf and .prj files) ?

Comment: Yeah i am aware.I will try and update

Comment: The Matcher Transformer will compare sources and then you can find the mis-match and send it out though a tester http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/matcher.htm

Comment: Could the comment provided by @Mapprez be converted as an answer ? The question looks as if it was unanswered.